# Is a redirection made in cPanel - a problem for Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, 301-redirect

My domain is gpj.rs
Google search console cannot indexing the home page
It says - there are pages with redirection
And lists the following examples:

```
http://www.gpj.rs/
http://gpj.rs/
```

Here is my redirection inside cPanel:

[image]

I made this redirection to simplify user expirience - i.e. to prevent http and www access

Is this redirection - the actual problem for Google?

My index.php is a very simple php page, without any redirection code inside

Thanks

Comment: cPanel makes the redirect by using the Apache htaccess. It is just a GUI interface which is often easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any requirement to have a 301 redirection for the following:

http://www.gpj.rs/
http://gpj.rs/

Previously you could have your property in the Search Console (Webmaster Tools) with either www or without www.  or, both.

Now Google Search Console gives you an option to have your property with just the domain name i.e. you can have your property with just gpj.rs.

In either of the above case, you do not need to set redirections.

Comment: I disagree. whats the point of having two urls with the sane content?

Comment: thanks a lot, but I cannot find Webmaster Tools inside Google Search Console. Could you specify where are the tools ?

Comment: Webmaster Tools was the original name. It was renamed to Google Search Console. So there is no webmaster tools anymore. If you search for Webmaster Tools on Google,  Google will take you to the Search Console.